# How to override spring active profile outside the classpath?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I want to be able to place a `application.properties` outside the classpath (eg on `d:/`), and there define the `spring.profile.active=production`.

If this is activated, spring should additionally load a properties file from classpath called `my-production.properties`.

I tried the following, which did not work. What might I have forgotten?

```
@Component
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:my-default.properties"),
    @PropertySource(value = "file:D:/my.properties"),
    @PropertySource(value = "classpath:my-${spring.profiles.active}.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
```

d:\my.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=production
```

my-default.properties:

```
testkey=default
```

my-production.properties:

```
testkey=production
```

App:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AppCfg {

    @Value("${testkey}")
    private String testkey;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Sysout(testkey); //prints: "default" instead of "production"
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO you are thinking and making it way to complex. Spring Boot will do it for you. Simply add a `spring.config.location` property and Spring Boot will also check that for properties files. No need to load you own and trying to get the profiles from it. See also http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

Comment: No, I don't want the configuration properties to be placed in an external location file (that I would specify with `spring.config.location`). I want `application-{profile}` files inside the classpath and just load them by externally defined `spring.profiles.active`.

Comment: isn't using `spring.profiles.active` dangerous. given that it can consist of multiple profiles one might add in random order? SB uses `application-${profile}.properties` by default.  see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment

Comment: Have actually read the documentation? With `spring.config.location` you add **additional** locations that Spring Boot takes into account. It isn't replacing the existing ones. I strongly suggest you first read the documentation...

Comment: I tried defining the `spring.config.location` in my `application.properties`, anyhow spring does not respect the properties found there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to put applciation properties in other location you can use command line arguments or enviroment variable.
See section **21.2 Application property files**
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/

If you just want to set the active profile, take a look at section **21. Externalized Configuration**
You can override the active profile property by using `OS environment variables` for example.

You can set `SPRING_CONFIG_NAME` and `SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION` environment variables to set the location of application.properties manually. Also you can use the `/config` subdir of the current directory or
the current directory to load the application.properties.

Comment: Using VM args indeed works, BUT I'd prefer having an external properties file where I just can put the active profile, without extra var args.